# How do I print a reversed times table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to print to screen this times table in reverse like the photo but can't figure what I need to change to do that.

```
var digit = 9, multiplier = 9, textresult = "", result = 0;
while (digit > 0) {
    for (multiplier = 9; multiplier >= digit; multiplier--) {
      result = digit * multiplier;
        if (digit == multiplier) {
         textresult += digit + " x " + multiplier + " = " + result + " 
           <br>";}
        else {
             textresult += digit + " x " + multiplier + " = " + result + 
             "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
     }
     digit--;}
     strong textdocument.write(textresult);
```

any Ideas?

[image: expected result image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this correction

```js
var digit = 1,
  textresult = "<pre><code>",
  max = 9;
while (digit <= max) {
  for (var multiplier = digit; multiplier <= max; multiplier++) {
    var result = digit * multiplier;
    textresult += digit + " * " + multiplier + " = " + result;
    if (10 > result) {
      textresult += " ";
    }
    if (max == multiplier) {
      textresult += "<br/>";
    } else {
      textresult += "  ";
    }
  }
  digit++;
}
textresult += "</pre></code>";
document.write(textresult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Count from `digit` of 1 up, rather than from 9 down. On each inner loop, initialize `multiplier` to `digit` instead of `9`, and similarly, count up with `multiplier`:

```js
var digit = 1,
  textresult = "";
while (digit < 10) {
  for (let multiplier = digit; multiplier < 10; multiplier++) {
    const result = digit * multiplier;
    textresult += digit + " x " + multiplier + " = " + result + (multiplier === 9 ? '<br>' : "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
    digit++;
  }
  document.write(textresult);
```